# Can I use a supercapacitor (like Maxwell boostCAP 3000F) on a coilgun?

Tags: coil, pulse, supercapacitor

Can someone tell me if I can use a supercapacitor (like Maxwell boostCAP 3000F) on a coilgun?

I want to obtain a very intense magnetic field for a project, and I'm not sure what capacitors should I use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: a super capacitor will not be useful at all in this scenario.

If you are trying to induce a large magnetic field the key is having a large amount of current dumped into the coil in a very short time. Having a large capacitance can actually make this process take *much longer* and you get a much smaller field out. The magnetic field from a coil is proportional to the rate of change of the current through the coil.

Do a little bit of research on the discharge rates of capacitors and you will see they are dependent on the initial voltage (which 2.7v from a super capacitor is too low to use for almost anything), the size of the capacitor, and the impedance of the load that is discharging the capacitor.

The key here is the balancing act between how much current you *want* and how much current you can use *before the coil burns up.*

**As always, be cautious and safe when using capacitors, especially at high voltages, as they can be very dangerous.**

PS: calling anything a "gun" may draw unwanted attention, use "projectile launcher." ;)

Comment: "Mass driver" is even better.

Comment: the magnetic field in a coil is not proportional to the rate of the current change!! it is proportional to the current!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Let's try it!

From [the datasheet:](http://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/k2series_ds_10153704.pdf)

- Capacity : 3000F
- Absolute Maximum Current : 1900A

Now the charge stored, Q, = C * V = 3000 * 2.7 = 8100 Coulombs.

So at Abs Max Current (1900A) discharge time can be as low as ...8100 / 1900 = 4.26 seconds.

So divide the length of the gun by 4.26 seconds to get the muzzle velocity.

For any reasonable size of gun, you could walk faster than the bullet.

(Edit : I am being a bit unfair : if 1900A is a useful current in launching a small, er, mass at high velocity, then the capacitor can launch a number of small masses over a 4 second burst. But as far as dumping all its energy (10.9kj) into one mass is concerned, that would take 4 seconds, for an average power about 2.5 kw. That's really not much by projectile launching standards.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to focus more on **high-voltage**, low-capacitance for higher energy projectiles; not the other way around. Although this is a new-guy mistake, so I would advise you read a bit more on designs like this, and basic electronics.

The long-term limit is overheating, not energy. Remember that and it gets clearer that you can put a hell of a lot of power in quite easily, but controlling it is not as easy.

Also rail guns are way cooler.

Answer (score 0):

Using a boostcap CAN work, I started working on one myself but never got around to finishing it unfortunately and due to divorce I now live in a small apt. where testing such a thing isn't feasible heh.

Anyway, the first thing you need to know is you CANNOT use a SCR to fire it.  It will take too long to discharge and melt your coil and plastic firing tube along with it.  My plan was to fire short bursts so I could fire multiple shots without a recharge.  Unfortunately, the firing timing circuit malfunctioned and left it on and that's exactly what happened lol.  What I did was used 50 MOSFETS in parallel connected together via 1" thick aluminum rails for the power rails and smaller ones for the gates.  You need the thickness because you are conducting a LOT of current, you want to keep resistance low so most of the voltage drops across your coil, plus it helps to heat sink your MOSFETS too.

You will need a timer circuit or an IR LED/detector setup to ensure you only activate the MOSFETS when needed.  You'll need a beefy current source for the MOSFETS plus high power bleed resistors since you want the MOSFETS to turn on and off quickly because unlike BJTs, MOSFETS have a gate capacitor that needs charged/discharged to turn it on/off.  If it helps, I used 5 boostcaps connected together with 1/4" thick aluminum plates and 10awg wire for the coil.  I had dual 4awg jumper wires to take the power from the cap bank to the the coil gun, which was sorta table mounted on a big piece of plastic.  The 10awg wire was selected because with low voltage, you need to keep resistance low too so you want thicker wire with less turns.  Unfortunately, even with that you won't get the shot power a single shot high voltage coil gun has.  BUT, you do get to fire it probably a few dozen times!  Also, it should have more power than battery versions due to the far lower current limitations of batteries.